# How do I change the pictures in the cell if it has been pressed?

Tags: ios

I have a TableView. How do I change the pictures in the cell if it has been pressed?

This code does not work

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell%d", indexPath.row] forIndexPath:indexPath];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSString *level =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"level"];
int intForStrin =[level intValue];
NSString *level11 =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"level11"];
int index =[level11 intValue];
UIImageView *imgView;
imgView =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(24, 13, 30, 30)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];

if (indexPath.row == 0 && index == 0) {
    if (intForStrin <= 6) {
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
    }
    else if (intForStrin <= 11) {
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
    }
    else if (intForStrin <= 16) {
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"];
    }
    else if (intForStrin <= 20) {
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"];
    }
}
if (indexPath.row == 1 && index == 1) {
    if (intForStrin <= 6) {

        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];
    }
    else if (intForStrin <= 11) {
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
    }
    else if (intForStrin <= 16) {
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"];
    }
    else if (intForStrin <= 20) {
        imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"];
    }
}
```

### ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use didSelectRowAtIndexPath in tableview api

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.imageview.image = "yourimage";
}
```

Comment: And if I need to change the image in several cells?

Comment: If you know the list of cells for which you need to change the image, you can create IndexPaths for those rows, fetch respective cell and set the new image to it.

Comment: So I'm doing. Add to question

Comment: Is this code in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function? It would be easier to help if you could post little for code

Comment: If you are not using a customized prototype cell, you should do the following. 1. There is no need to create a new `UIImageView` object for the cell and add it to `contentView`, remove those two lines. 2. instead of the this line, `imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];`, you should set the cell's imageView property. `cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];`

Comment: Do you see the initial image set in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function in your table view? Can you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function as well?

Comment: get all visible cells index from tableview and change image accordinglly.

Comment: @R P Add to question. Default image задаю в StoryBoard